# Send parameter to controller in Yii

Tags: php, url, yii, query-string

I am working on admin panel in yii and want to update record so when so i want to send record id on href click so url become

```
http://localhost/firstapp/backend/vehicle/edit/1
```

but its not working it gives error as "Unable to resolve the request "backend/vehicle"." I am trying this from long time please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variable by get method, like "/site/index?asd=xyz&pqr=qwe" and this can be access by $_GET.

If you want to pass variable in codeigniter style, i.e. by using '/', You can use name parameter in url manager. You can get more info here : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-named-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information about your question for better help.
However, suppose you have `www.example.com/controller/action` url. if you want to pass some variable to `action`, first you need to define a rule in url manager in `config/main.php` like this:

```
"controller/action/<variable1>/<variable2>"=>"controller/action"
```

Now if the url was "controller/action/test1/test2", in your `action` the value of `$_GET['variable1']` will equal to "test1" and `$_GET['variable12']` will equal to "test2" .
Note that user-defined url manager rules must be BEFORE the yii default url manager rules.